# Importing AdWords Call Conversions to Analytics without CID - only gCLID - with Measurement Protocol

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

We have an Google Adwords account linked up to a Google Universal Analytics account and we are trying to attribute call extension conversions to the Adwords via Analytics using only the gCLID. We are getting the gCLIDs via the Google Adwords API.

In other words, we get these Google click IDs (gCLID) from the Google click metrics report every time there is a click to call on our ad. However, since the user never actually goes to the site, it is impossible to grab the Google Analytics CID to identify an Analytics session.

We would like to import these gCLIDs to Analytics and have them attributed to our Adwords account by sending events using the measurement protocol. These are the parameters that we are sending with MP so far but with no success as of yet.

`v: "1",
tid: "UA-xxxxxxx-x",
cid: "555",
gclid: CMvmjrWWvdECFQONaQo,
t: "event",
ec: "SEM Call",
ea: "Call Placed",
cn: "NADA Event",
ci: "xxxxxxxxx",
cs: "google",
cm: "cpc",
ev: 27,
kc: +nada`

The event source / medium turn out to be correct but Analytics doesn't seem to realize that we are trying to import conversions to attribute and link with our Adwords account.

We know that importing directly to Adwords is a possibility, but we would rather import directly to Analytics if possible, due to other tracking issues.

Can anyone help me attribute my gCLIDS (conversions) to my Adwords account and specifically, to Adwords keywords, in this way?

UPDATE: I'm still having the same problem; that is, t event registers as a new session and does not attribute to the linked AdWords campaign/keyword. I understand why there is a new session because I don't have access to the CID param. However, I don't understand why it will not link to the AdWords info in Analytics since I am providing the GCLID param.

I am currently trying to import directly to AdWords using a CSV with the GCLIDs from the click report and even that is failing. In AdWords, I tried both "import from clicks" and "import from calls" using csv. The first tracking status just keeps saying "no recent conversions" and the latter displays "unverified". I can understand the unverified because we aren't tracking calls from the website, only call extensions and click-to-call. The import from calls will be unverified until it sees the JS tag on the website is set up, as I understand it, and we have no reason to do that.

At the end of the day we are trying to get our GCLIDs generated from call extensions and click-to-call "clicks" that we are pulling from the click_metrics_report to attribute to the proper AdWords Keyword and Campaign. It doesn't matter at this point whether it is through GA or AdWords.

Any ideas?

As a last resort, for lack of a better plan, I am going to set the Measurement Protocol events as a goal, and then import the goal into AdWords. With any luck the GCLID param that I pass to GA will carry over through the goal into AdWords and attribute correctly.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Also, we are not prepared to use Google forwarding numbers as we have a third party call tracking service that uses specific phone numbers.